# Facebook Recent Activity

Tags: facebook

If someone is viewing my Facebook page they cannot see any recent activity that I've done. They can't see if I've added a friend, commented on someone else's photo or made a post to a friends wall. All my settings are set to "Friends" so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Why did you tag it as Google if it's a facebook question?!

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to hide your recent activity, then there is a way to do that in the new Facebook timeline. Click the close 'x' button for that post and select 'Hide all recent activity from Timeline' option. In the future similar posts will not appear in the timeline.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! I didn't really clarify but my intention is to actually make my recent activity visible. If a friend is viewing my wall no recent activity that I've done shows up on my page although I can see it on my own page. All my settings are set to "Friends" and I have not hidden anything by clicking on the "x" to remove any recent activity.